# SwiftUI, How to change one button label with multiple buttons and one Bool Condition

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, view, label

my problem is that I don't wanna declare multiple Bool var for these code , and i wanna change the exact button pressed Label , Not All

@State var buttonClicked : Bool

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("Size")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
        Spacer()
        Button {
            self.buttonClicked.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("US")
                .foregroundColor(buttonClicked ? .black : .gray.opacity(0.5))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
        Button {
            self.buttonClicked.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("UK")
                .foregroundColor(buttonClicked ? .black : .gray.opacity(0.5))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
        Button {
            buttonClicked.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("EU")
                .foregroundColor(buttonClicked ? .black : .gray.opacity(0.5))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can set your options into something reusable like an array you can eliminate the duplicate code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MultiButtonView: View {
    @State var buttonClicked : String = ""
    let options = ["US", "UK", "EU"]
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Size")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
            ForEach(options, id:\.description) { option in
                Button {
                    self.buttonClicked = option
                } label: {
                    Text(option)
                        .foregroundColor(buttonClicked == option ? .black : .gray.opacity(0.5))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `[Bool]`:

```
@State var buttons = [false, false, false]
```

```
Button {
    buttons[0].toggle()
} label: {
    Text("US")
        .foregroundColor(buttons[0] ? .black : .gray.opacity(0.5))
        .fontWeight(.bold)
}
Button {
    buttons[1].toggle()
} label: {
    Text("UK")
        .foregroundColor(buttons[1] ? .black : .gray.opacity(0.5))
        .fontWeight(.bold)
}
Button {
    buttons[2].toggle()
} label: {
    Text("EU")
        .foregroundColor(buttons[2] ? .black : .gray.opacity(0.5))
        .fontWeight(.bold)
}
```

Note that you don't have to repeat the buttons if you make a struct that represents each button's label and state:

```
struct ToggleButtonModel: Identifiable {
    let label: String
    var clicked: Bool = false
    var id: String { label }
}
```

```
@State var buttons: [ToggleButtonModel] = [.init(label: "US"), .init(label: "UK"), .init(label: "EU")]
```

With this, you can use a `ForEach`:

```
ForEach($buttons) { button in
    Button {
        button.clicked.wrappedValue.toggle()
    } label: {
        Text(button.wrappedValue.label)
            .foregroundColor(button.clicked.wrappedValue ? .black : .gray.opacity(0.5))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
}
```

Also consider using a `Toggle` with `.button` toggle style:

```
ForEach($buttons) { button in
    Toggle(isOn: button.clicked) {
        Text(button.wrappedValue.label)
            .foregroundColor(button.clicked.wrappedValue ? .black : .gray.opacity(0.5))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
}
.toggleStyle(.button)
```